# psycopg2 strange behavior

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg

```
from django.db import connection

q = 'some value'

sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE %%%s%%' % q
sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE %%'+ q +'%%'

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute( sql1 ) #why exception: IndexError: tuple index out of range ?
cursor.execute( sql2 ) #works ok
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to QUOTE properly your SQL arguments.

And by ***quoting properly*** I mean using the quote facility provided by DBAPI, not adding a ' around your string, which is useless.

Correct code :

```
q = "%"+q+"%"
cursor.execute( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE %s', (q,) )
```

Really correct code :

```
q = "%"+q.replace("%","%%")+"%"
cursor.execute( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE %s', (q,) )
```

Suppose q = "a'bc"
First, rewrite this as "%a'bc%"
Then use it as a normal string argument. psycopg will rewrite it as '%a\'bc%' as it should.

If q may contain "%" and you want to search for it, then use the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Using direct string manipulation will almost certainly lead to improper SQL that is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks ([see psycopg2's comments on the subject](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)).

What I think you're looking to do is try and perform a LIKE '%some value%' in django, right?:

```
from django.db import connection
q = '%some value%'
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE %(my_like)s", {'my_like': q})
```

As of psycopg2 2.4.1, the SQL that is executed on the server is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%some value%'
```

Comment: For those who don't follow the link: "Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint."

Answer (score 0):

You need to QUOTE properly your SQL command:

```
sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%%%s%%'" % q
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%"+ q +"%'"
```

And by **quoting properly** I mean using single quotes with `LIKE` expressions.

Comment: Ooops. I mistype in question. Really variables: sql1 and sql2 like in your comment

Comment: SQL injection here, since q is not quoted properly.